# Pre fill a date in Woocommerce Bookings plugin from another page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Tribe's Event Calendar and Woocommerce's Booking plugins to try and create a site where you can see yoga classes and then book a spot in one of the classes.

What I'd like to do is, from the Event Calendar page for a particular class (eg: the March 12th, 2015 class), have a button that has the date & time data that can pass that data to the Woocommerce product page with the date picker then filled in with that data.

I've noticed that when you select a date, admin-ajax.php fires off a POST with

```
wc_bookings_field_start_date_day=12&wc_bookings_field_start_date_month=03&wc_bookings_field_start_date_year=2015&wc_bookings_field_start_date_time=&add-to-cart=191
```

in it. Can this be done via a POST from another page, and if so, how?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?